# C++11 Recursive Spinlock Implementation

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11

Following [this code review post](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/95590/c11-recursive-atomic-spinlock) I tried to implement a recursive spin lock as follows.

```
class SpinLock {
public:
  SpinLock() : lock_owner(lock_is_free), lock_count(0) {
  }

  inline bool tryLock() {
    if (lock_owner != std::this_thread::get_id()) {
      bool locked = lock_owner.compare_exchange_strong(lock_is_free,
          std::this_thread::get_id(), std::memory_order_acquire,
          std::memory_order_relaxed);
      if (locked) {
        lock_count++;
      }
      return locked;
    }

    lock_count++;
    return true;
  }

  inline void lock() {
    if (lock_owner != std::this_thread::get_id()) {
      while(!lock_owner.compare_exchange_weak(lock_is_free,
            std::this_thread::get_id(), std::memory_order_acquire,
            std::memory_order_relaxed));
      assert(lock_owner == std::this_thread::get_id());
    } else {
      printf("Recursive locking\n");
    }

    lock_count++;
  }

  inline void unlock() {
    assert(lock_owner == std::this_thread::get_id());
    assert(lock_count != 0);

    --lock_count;
    if (lock_count == 0) {
      lock_owner.store(lock_is_free, std::memory_order_release);
    }
  }

  inline bool isOwner() {
    return lock_owner == std::this_thread::get_id();
  }

  inline bool isSet() {
    return lock_owner != lock_is_free;
  }
 
private:
  std::thread::id lock_is_free;
  std::atomic<std::thread::id> lock_owner;
  int lock_count;
};
```

But ***lock*** method doesn't seem to ensure mutual exclusion when I tried locking with multiple threads. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: It is supposed to contain a std::thread::id which does not point to any thread. http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/id/id

Comment: `compare_exchange_weak` stores the current value of the atomic in the first argument (which is passed by reference). You ruin `lock_is_free` variable - it takes on the ID of some random thread. You need to use a local variable, initialized to `thread::id()` each time through the loop. I don't see how the member variable `lock_is_free` is at all useful.

Comment: `std::thread::id` on Windows MSVS2013 implementation: `typedef struct { void *_Hnd; unsigned int _Id; } _Thrd_imp_t;`, i.e. 12 bytes=(8 ptr + 4 uint). So all operations implemented in `std::atomic<std::thread::id>` will use mutex or other locks, also may be other spinlock :) "All atomic types except for std::atomic_flag may be implemented **using mutexes or other locking** operations, rather than using the lock-free atomic CPU instructions."   http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic/is_lock_free

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments, `compare_exchange_weak` replaces the contents of the first arguments if the condition is false, so `lock_is_free` is corrupted.

Further, this is not valid code because `compare_exchange_weak` compares the value of the objects stored in the `atomic` variable in bitwise order, so as if they were compared using `std::memcmp`.  And an object of type `std::thread::id` is not an integral type and has a special overload for comparisons.  So does `pthread_t` (`pthread_equal`), so essentially you are relying on implementation defined behavior.

You can confirm that by running the following code

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <pthread.h>
using std::cout;
using std::endl;

int main() {
    cout << std::boolalpha << std::is_integral<std::thread::id>::value << endl;
    cout << std::boolalpha << std::is_integral<decltype(pthread_self())>::value
        << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Why not just overload `memcpy` and `memcmp` to work with `std::thread::id` in that case?  Both [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic/compare_exchange) and [cplusplus.com](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/atomic/atomic/compare_exchange_weak/) confirm that there is no guarantee in.  Even overloading `memcpy` (both globally and in the `std` namespace) doesn't work on my system with my standard library.  I suspect it will not on most other systems (standard library and compiler combination) as well because of two reasons:

1. `compare_exchange_weak` might not use `memcpy` or `memcmp` under the hood and might roll its own implementation
2. Although it is not needed casting a pointer to `void*` before passing it to `memcpy` or `memcmp` might choose the default implementation anyway that is not correct

See the code below for an explanation of what I meant in the 2nd point

```
void func(void*) {
    cout << "void*" << endl;
}
void func(int*) {
    cout << "int*" << endl;
}

int main() {
    int a = 1;
    func(&a);
    func(reinterpret_cast<void*>(a));

    return 0;
}
```

To answer your question, using `compare_exchange_weak` with `std::thread::id` isn't correct ("not portable" might be better) code.

Comment: Great! I see that's what tripped me off. Thanks for the additional explanation on std::thread::id.

Comment: cppreference didn't miss it, it's pretty much the first thing it says "...if those are bitwise-equal ... Otherwise, loads the actual value stored in `*this` into `expected` (performs load operation)" http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic/compare_exchange

Comment: @Cubbi oh :( It seems like I missed it somehow

Comment: Also on GCC (Linux)`std::atomic<std::thread::id>` is lock-free http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c74ad5a84ad90333 but on MSVS2013(Windows) it is **not lock-free**. In the file xthrcommon.h type `std::thread::id` contains this: `typedef struct { void *_Hnd; unsigned int _Id; } _Thrd_imp_t;` Also **`float` is not integral, but is lock-free:** http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/30e89d2c9b99ccb7 then `std::thread::id` does not have to be an integral type to be used as:`std::atomic<std::thread::id> lock_owner; lock_owner.compare_exchange_weak(..)`, if is non-POD type then  usually not lock-free.